# Синтаксическая ошибка: идентификатор "list", в определении функции, среди множества <<>>

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.
Делаю свою реализацию map, и вот такая вот конструкция не дает скомпилироваться проекту.

```
void traverse(node<key, value> p, list<node<key, value>> &l) { ... }
```

Ошибка такая:

> Ошибка    C2061   синтаксическая ошибка: идентификатор "list"

list стандартный, из stl библиотеки.

Расставлял пробелы среди скобок, ничего не помогает.

Comment: А если `std::list`?

Comment: Либо не подключили `#include <list>` либо не добавили `using namespace std;`.

Comment: У GCC, например,  крыша едет от  >> в конкретизации шаблона, надо пробелами разбивать.

Comment: @gbg не в gcc дело. Беспробельные << и >> разрешили в шаблонах, начиная с C++11. Вероятно студия версии ТС не поддерживает C++11. И действительно нужны пробелы. Ну или остальные, уже высказанные, версии имеют место быть.